# Get Full Page Source From Walmart

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Note up front: very amateur coder, hence why my request is so direct.

Trying to get the UPC from the page source of https://www.walmart.com/ip/Rice-Krispies-Treats-Original-Chewy-Crispy-Marshmallow-Squares-Ready-to-Eat-12-4-oz-16-Count/10818666?athbdg=L1600&from=/search
The UPC is only in the page source, not on the page itself.

I have a couple different pieces of code that work, but get caught up in Walmart's CAPTCHA "Activate and hold the button to confirm that you’re human. Thank You!" I don't know the first thing of trying to bypass this. Need help going the next step and getting what I would if I did right-click and View page source.

Also, FWIW I am using Anaconda Jupyter Lab.

- TAKE 1

  ```
  #import urllib2
  import urllib.request as urllib2

  response = urllib2.urlopen("http://google.de")
  page_source = response.read()
  page_source
  ```
- TAKE 2

  ```
  response = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.walmart.com/ip/Rice-Krispies-Treats-Original-Chewy-Crispy-Marshmallow-Squares-Ready-to-Eat-12-4-oz-16-Count/10818666?athbdg=L1600&from=/search")
  page_source = response.read()
  page_source
  ```
- TAKE 3

  ```
  #pip install -U selenium

  from selenium import webdriver
  import time
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  chrome_options = Options()
  chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
  driver.get("https://www.walmart.com/ip/Rice-Krispies-Treats-Original-Chewy-Crispy-Marshmallow-Squares-Ready-to-Eat-12-4-oz-16-Count/10818666?athbdg=L1600&from=/search")

  time.sleep(10)

  html_source = driver.page_source
  html_source
  ```

Comment: Where is the UPC on the page? Is it only in the source? I looked and I didn't see it but there's a LOT of info on the page.

Comment: Correct, just in the source